# How to check if the direct path between two cells in a 2D array is blocked by a given cell?

Tags: c

What is the simplest way to tell if the straight line between cell A and cell B is blocked by cell C? i.e.

If cell A is [0, 0], cell B is [2, 2], and cell C is [1,1], cell C blocks the path between cells A and B. If cell B was any other cell in that diagonal ([3, 3], [4, 4], etc.), cell C would still block the path between cell A and B. But if cell C is any other cell, it doesn't block that path.

Like, using the locations of cells A, B, and C, what conditionals would I have to check for this?

Comment: are these always horizontal, vertical or 45 degree diagonal or how?

Comment: Yes, horizontally, vertically, or in any 45 degree diagonal.

Comment: Even in general case, you can consider AB and AC as vectors, and if the [determinant is zero](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/clifford/algebra/functions/determinant/index.htm), they're collinear, then you just need to see if AB is in the same direction as AC and that AC is shorter than AB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple linear algebra. Consider two vectors, AB and AC; they're parallel if the determinant is zero. They're pointing to the same direction if dot product is positive. And C is along the path AB, if the previous were true and AC is shorter than AB. To see if AC is shorter than AB we can compare squares of their lengths, avoiding the square root.

Thus we can work this out with additions, subtractions and multiplications in constant time. It even works for **all** exact integer coordinates; the lines do not need to be horizontal, vertical or diagonal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct vec { int x; int y; };

int determinant(struct vec a, struct vec b) {
    return a.x * b.y - b.x * a.y;
}

int dot_product(struct vec a, struct vec b) {
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y;
}

int len_squared(struct vec v) {
    return dot_product(v, v);
}

int blocks(struct vec a, struct vec b, struct vec c) {
    struct vec ab = {b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y};
    struct vec ac = {c.x - a.x, c.y - a.y};

    return determinant(ab, ac) == 0 &&
           dot_product(ab, ac) > 0 &&
           len_squared(ac) < len_squared(ab);
}

int main(void) {
    struct vec a = {0, 0}, b = {2, 2}, c = {1, 1};
       
    if (blocks(a, b, c)) {
        puts("Blocks");
    }
    else {
        puts("Does not block");
    }
}
```